# ExtAudioFileRead crash with code -40

Tags: core-audio, audiounit, ios8.1

My app plays music in background. I have **audio** key **on** in Background modes, my audio session looks like:

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
NSError *err = NULL;
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&err];
if( err ){
    NSLog(@"There was an error creating the audio session");
}
[audioSession setMode:AVAudioSessionModeDefault error:&err];
if( err ){
    NSLog(@"There was an error setting mote to the audio session");
}
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&err];
if( err ){
    NSLog(@"There was an error setting mote to the audio session");
}
```

I'm playing via AUGraph which is configured with 2 nodes: Remote I/O and Mixer:

```
AudioComponentDescription outputcd;
outputcd.componentFlags        = 0;
outputcd.componentFlagsMask    = 0;
outputcd.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
outputcd.componentSubType      = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO;
outputcd.componentType         = kAudioUnitType_Output;

// Multichannel mixer unit
AudioComponentDescription MixerUnitDescription;
MixerUnitDescription.componentType          = kAudioUnitType_Mixer;
MixerUnitDescription.componentSubType       = kAudioUnitSubType_AU3DMixerEmbedded;
MixerUnitDescription.componentManufacturer  = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
MixerUnitDescription.componentFlags         = 0;
MixerUnitDescription.componentFlagsMask     = 0;
```

Also according to [Technical QA](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1606/_index.html) I added

```
UInt32 maxFPS = 4096;
AudioUnitSetProperty(_mixerUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_MaximumFramesPerSlice,kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &maxFPS,sizeof(maxFPS));
```

But still no luck, my app keeps crashing on **ExtAudioFileRead** in Render callback function approx 10 seconds as i lock iPhone. Any suggestions? 
Important to mention this bug is not reproduced on ios 7.

Comment: My further research showed that this bug is reproduced on iOS 8.1.2 only. Apparently this is iOS bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with Data Protection enabled in app capabilities. So as device was locked, files got encrypted and could not be played in background. Hence the crash. 
Changing encryption properties for audio files fixes this issue.